# Cannot use C++ static variable in Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, static, android-ndk

I have the following C++ class in `Foo.cpp`:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
    static int bar;

    static void set(int _bar) {
        Foo::bar = _bar;
    }

    static int get() {
        return bar;
    }
};

int Foo::bar;
```

I want to include it in my NDK project. I want to access Foo::bar in my NDK endpoint, which implements native method, like this:

```
#include "Foo.cpp"
```

They're both located in the same folder, same library (smae `add_library` function in CMakeLists.txt). However, when I compile the code, it states that there was `multiple definition of Foo::bar`, and pointing to the NDK endpoint as the place where the static variable was first defined.

I did try to put the whole Foo class in namespace like this:

```
namespace {
    // The above class Foo here
}
```

It did compile but quit as soon as I started the application. How to fix this? Thanks!

I has a Java background so I'm expecting to have something similar to "normal" Java static.

Comment: Put the class definition in a header file, which you then include from any file that wants to use `Foo`. Then create a `Foo.cpp` file which contains the definition for `Foo::bar`, i.e. the line `int Foo::bar;`. Do not include the .cpp file in other files - only include the corresponding header file.

Comment: Thank you @Michael. This looks like one hell of a rookie mistake!